# How to set project wide variables

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to define `project wide` environment variables? I'm aware of the function specific variables that you can access like

```
    let url = process.env.DB_URL
    let user = process.env.DB_USER
    let password = process.env.DB_PASSWORD
```

but I can't find any way or documentation for project wide variables. As I have write, read, ... functions that in the above example all use database credentials, I would like to specify those on project level instead for each function.

Comment: Are you referring to functions deployed with gcloud, or functions deployed using the Firebase tools that extend GCF?

Comment: as specified in the title and in the tag, it's about Google Cloud Functions and not Firebase. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCF on its own doesn't offer the thing you're looking for.  You're going to have to set up some other source of data within your project using another GCP product, and query it from your function code.

Any product that persists data and is queryable will do, including any database. A Firestore document is easy enough to set up and edit.  You will want to query the data on every function invocation if you want your code to respond to changes in the data source quickly.

Another alternative is to deploy every function every time you want a configuration change, and write a script that sets the environment the same for each function deployment. This is similar to the way Firebase deploys functions by default using [environment variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#env-variables).

Comment: wow, that seems excessive. do you maybe know what the motivation behind this is?  having project level env vars seems like an obvious choice so I'm struggeling to understand this architectural choice. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your functions are logically grouped together by some common code or config, then it makes sense for them to have a shared codebase and be deployed together.  That's why Firebase went ahead and provided a pattern with that model.  Otherwise, they are independent from each other, perhaps serving very different purposes with little to nothing in common, and making them share common config means you can now accidentally affect one function by intending to only change the config for another.  Keeping them isolated *by default* is a good policy to prevent these sort of "contamination" errors.

Comment: But I didn't build this thing - I can only tell you that there are many reasons why someone would deploy multiple functions in a project, and erring on the side of safety is usually the best bet for flexible products.

Comment: Also it's maybe good to understand that the isolation is a result of each function existing in its own dedicated docker container, quite *literally* isolated from the runtime behavior of all other function.  This is an important feature to keeps things small, fast, and predictable. If this isn't the behavior you're looking for, then make GCF isn't right for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for all the details! I guess I need to dig deeper into Firebase - until then, I'll just create copies of each function. This way everything _gets copied_ to the new function. I can already see this being annoying if I need to chance credentials though - as I use functions to gain speed during development and to do a quick prototype, I don't want to learn Firebase just to get configs rolled out. This will be a problem for future me.